# find input type text inside div by using div class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simple form where I'm using label and input text field

```js
//In below javascript function i'm trying to read the value of text input as

jQuery(this).find(".fr_field_wrapper .fr_half").each(function(i, obj) {
  var addValue = jQuery(this).find("text").val();
  if (addValue == undefined || addValue == null || addValue != "") {
    addValue = jQuery(this).find("select").val();
  }
  var labelval = jQuery(this).find("label").text().trim().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");

  AllElements.push({
    id: _elementid,
    label: labelval,
    value: addValue,
    type: 'address'
  });
});

//where 'addValue' is undefined for textboxes
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fr_grid">
  <div class="fr_half has_sub_label">
    <label class="fr_sub_label">City</label>
    <input type="text" data-rv-input="model.value.city">
  </div>
  <div class="fr_half has_sub_label">
    <label class="fr_sub_label">
    ZIP Code
  </label>
    <input type="text" data-rv-input="model.value.zipcode">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure `text` is `tag<text>`?

Comment: `jQuery(this).find("input").val()`

Comment: oh my actually it was jQuery(this).find("input[type=text]").val() pasting mistake.

Comment: You can use `:text` as a shorthand for `input[type=text]`

Comment: There's no `class="fr_field_wrapper"` in your HTML.

Comment: class="fr_field_wrapper" is parent div class just top of the fr_grid, i think issue is i'm not able to find input value because same script is returning value of select option

Comment: thanks @Barmar  ':text' shorthand worked for me but i'm not sure why jQuery(this).find("input").val() is undefined

Comment: What is `this` when the code is called? Is this code inside an event handler?